# Examples of web services with basic authentication on the internet?

Tags: json, web-services, rest, soap

Are there any web services available on the internet which require basic username/password authentication?

Any kind of service would do: SOAP, REST, JSON, XML style...

I need one for my testing, but it looks like most web APIs these days are either publicly available or use OAuth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP Client Testing Service at [httpbin.org](http://httpbin.org/) offers this functionality for testing.